# Using a C++ library in Javascript function on the user's browser

Tags: javascript, c++, seal

I want to a web application that concerns Homomorphic Encryption. I am using Microsoft SEAL. I wanted to know if there is any way I could use this library in javascript function so that whenever a button is clicked the javascript function is executed on the **user's browser** and the encryption is carried out using Microsoft SEAL. I tried emscripten but the C++ code importing the library SEAL is not generating a wasm file. I have spent alot of time trying to find a solution but no luck. All the solutions available result in the code executed on the server. If anyone knows a way I can achieve this please guide me.
The help would be really highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd silently close all my browsers forever, if executing an arbitarary C++ code loaded  from an arbitrary web page would be possible in browsers.

Comment: If you want to compile C++ code to run in the browser then Emscripten is the right tool. I suggest you ask a question about compiling this SEAL library to WASM and using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

There is an open source library, [node-seal](https://github.com/morfix-io/node-seal), which is a nearly complete port of Microsoft SEAL to WebAssembly (WASM) and should be able to accommodate the majority of use-cases. It works with NodeJS and in modern browsers.

There is also a website, [morfix.io](https://morfix.io/sandbox), where you may test and experiment with it inside your browser. You may even generate working code using node-seal.

Full disclosure, I’m the author of node-seal and the web demo.

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing this. Would you have a tutorial for using this implementation? If yes, could you please share it? It would be a huge help. Thanks

Comment: A tutorial maybe a little lengthy for this forum. I've written a small section [here](https://github.com/morfix-io/node-seal/blob/HEAD/USAGE.md) about the basics, but ultimately you will need to learn from trial and error.

The best documentation can be found from [Microsoft SEAL's C++ examples](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/tree/master/native/examples). 

Figuring out where to start can be challenging. There's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaYEHnaAg8M) that can explain in more detail. If I've answered your initial question I would be grateful for a positive vote.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to up vote your answer but yeah this was exactly what I had asked for. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer is what I meant. Thank you!